# EditText onTouchListener not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

I have created customized editText. Its onTouchListner is not calling at all.
what might be the reason? OnClickListener is also not calling, however addtextchangedlistener is working fine.
here is the code

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText implements OnTouchListener{
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 13;
    String value = "";
    final String viewMode = "editing";
    final String viewSide = "right";
    final Drawable x;
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
         x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            this.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
        }

        setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public synchronized boolean onEditorAction(TextView v,
                    int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("=====ontouchhhh");
            if (getCompoundDrawables()[viewSide.equals("left") ? 0 : 2] == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return false;
            }
            // x pressed
            if ((viewSide.equals("left") && event.getX() < getPaddingLeft()
                    + x.getIntrinsicWidth())
                    || (viewSide.equals("right") && event.getX() > getWidth()
                            - getPaddingRight() - x.getIntrinsicWidth())) {
                Drawable x3 = viewMode.equals("never") ? null : viewMode
                        .equals("always") ? x
                        : viewMode.equals("editing") ? null : viewMode
                                .equals("unlessEditing") ? x : null;
                System.out.println("=====cleared");
                setText("");
                setCompoundDrawables(null, null,
                        viewSide.equals("right") ? x3 : null, null);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



        // The height will be set the same with [X] icon
        setHeight(x.getBounds().height());

        x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Drawable x2 = viewMode.equals("never") ? null : viewMode
                .equals("always") ? x : viewMode.equals("editing") ? (value
                .equals("") ? null : x)
                : viewMode.equals("unlessEditing") ? (value.equals("") ? x
                        : null) : null;
        // #25317: Display search icon in text field
        final Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);
        searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                x.getIntrinsicHeight());

        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, viewSide.equals("right") ? x2
                : null, null);

setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("===onclick");
    }
});


        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                Drawable x4 = viewMode.equals("never") ? null : viewMode
                        .equals("always") ? x
                        : viewMode.equals("editing") ? (getText().toString()
                                .equals("") ? null : x) : viewMode
                                .equals("unlessEditing") ? (getText()
                                .toString().equals("") ? x : null) : null;
                setCompoundDrawables(null, null,
                        viewSide.equals("right") ? x4 : null, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s != null && s.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
                    setText(s.subSequence(0, MAX_LENGTH));
                    setSelection(MAX_LENGTH);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: You've implemented the `OnTouchListener` interface, but you never set the `View` as its own `OnTouchListener`. That's all unnecessary, though. Just override the `View`'s `onTouchEvent()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. Code edited. Still not working

Comment: Well, there's several things that could be wrong. You're only implementing one constructor. Are you sure the `View` is being instantiated with that one? Are you sure that this class is actually what's being used? Are you sure this `View` isn't being covered/blocked by another? Also, I would still recommend that you not set an `OnTouchListener`, but rather override the `onTouchEvent()`. And janki makes a good point below. Do you know what you should be looking for in your logcat?

Comment: do you know the reason of returning true or false from any listener ? coz i am seeing so many return statements with true-false..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is tangled
But you try this code

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //your code
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //your code
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //your code
                    break;

                    default:
            }

            return true;
        }
});
```

you must not implementing OnTouchListener